# Show ROS_DEBUG ROS_INFO with catkin_make run_tests

Tags: ros, rostest, gtest, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I create a minimal example in order to illustrate my question. If i do the following small testcase:

```
class SimpleTest : public ::testing::Test
{
 protected:
  virtual void SetUp(){return;}
  virtual void TearDown() {}
};

TEST_F(SimpleTest, OutputTest)
{
  ROS_DEBUG("Test Debug");
  ROS_INFO("Test Info");
  ROS_ERROR("Test Error");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "simple_test");
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle;

  if( ros::console::set_logger_level(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, ros::console::levels::Debug) )
     ros::console::notifyLoggerLevelsChanged();

  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

if I run the test with

```
 catkin_make run_tests
```

it will only display the output from ROS_ERROR.

However if I run it via rostest and --text

```
rostest --text hello_world simple.test
```

it will show the output from ROS_DEBUG and ROS_INFO.

I would like to achieve the same output with catkin_make run_tests.
So far I have trouble even understanding what is happening here and how the output can be different since essentially the same executable is called.

Any hints/recommendations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282657/show-ros_debug-ros_info-with-catkin_make-run_tests/) by [agutenkunst](https://answers.ros.org/users/30729/agutenkunst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2018-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into a variant of this problem. In my case, the first test would print ROS_INFO messages, but subsequent tests wouldn't. I found it necessary to call ros::init and other ROS calls AFTER calling InitGoogleTests. I updated the ROS gtest wiki page at http://wiki.ros.org/gtest  to show an example of initializing ROS after initializing gtest. I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) with karma: 300 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mpark](https://answers.ros.org/users/34669/mpark/) on 2018-04-16**:
I see the same issue w.r.t. only seeing the first ROS_INFO output when running gtest.  @PaulBouchier, what did you do to get around this?  I couldn't find anything on the wiki for gtest that shows a workaround.

**Comment by [dong](https://answers.ros.org/users/818/dong/) on 2020-01-03**:
I ran into the same problem. As suggested by http://wiki.ros.org/gtest You also need to add an additional ros::NodeHandle nh; between ros::init and RUN_ALL_TESTS();  so that the logging messages from all the test cases can be displayed.